# Editing other members

Tags: solspace-user

Can't seem to edit another member using 'User' by solspace using {exp:user:edit}.

I can edit as a super admin, but not when logged in as custom member group.

When logged in as the custom member group i get a no results instead of my templated edit form.

Is it possible to edit other members not using a super admin account?

```
{exp:user:edit 
    password_required="yes" 
    screen_name_password_required="yes"
    return="account/profile/{segment_3}/success" 
    username="{segment_3}"
    username_override="yes
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to goto Members > Member Groups > for the member group in question click Edit Group. After that scroll down to the Control Panel Administration section and set Can administrate members accounts to Yes. Save the page and try the User template tags again.

If you are still not able to edit a member group from that account you would need to add `group_id='X|Y'` to your edit forms for any additional member groups other then super admins that you want to be able to edit entries.